# iPad: UISplitViewController with iAds AdBanner in Detail View - Sizing

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, iad

When in landscape mode, the UISplitViewController displays the detail and master views.

The detail view has an **AdBanner** in it. However, when we set the AdBanner's **CurrentContentSizeIdentifier** to **SizeIdentifierLandscape** the banner is too wide for the detail view.

How can we put AdBanners in the Detail view of a UISplitViewController?

Comment: Hi there. Just experiencing this problem myself.  Which sof Anomie's solutions did you go with in the end out of interest? Cheers, Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a banner with `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` fits, you could use that.

Or you could put the ad banner view on top of the UISplitViewController's view in the UIWindow and construct your sub-controllers in such a way that it looks right with the ad banner overlapped, although that may give you other problems when it comes to orientation updates.

Or you could try adding the ad banner as a subview of the UISplitViewController's view, and possibly also adjust the positions of its other subviews to try to get things to not overlap, but this may or may not be allowed if you want your app approved for the app store.

Otherwise you're just out of luck.